Does the field inside a hollow conductor affect the field outside - an apparent contradiction with Gauß
$\phi(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_V d^3y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \rho(\vec{y})+ \oint_{\partial V} d^2y \vec{n}\cdot \nabla_y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) w(y)$
In class we derived this general solution to Poisson's equation in the volume V. G is a green's functions that is zero on the boundary of V, and w is the dirichlet boundary condition on the boundary of V. I am having trouble understanding why this equation doesn't imply that the E-field outside a conductor isn't affected by what's inside the conductor. My thought process is the following:
Let R3 be split into V1 and V2 where V1 represents a conductor and V2 everything outside it, we know that the surface of a conductor is an equipotential surface, so we can set that potential= 0 because the potential is only determined up to a constant, and we want the potential to be zero at infinity.
$$\partial V_2= \partial V_1 + \partial \mathbb{R}^3$$
$\phi(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_{V_2} d^3y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \rho(\vec{y})+ \oint_{\partial V_1 + \partial \mathbb{R}^3} d^2y \vec{n}\cdot \nabla_y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) w(y) \\ = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_{V_2} d^3y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \rho(\vec{y}) + \oint_{\partial V_1 } d^2y \vec{n}\cdot \nabla_y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) w(y) + \oint_{\partial \mathbb{R}^3} d^2y \vec{n}\cdot \nabla_y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) w(y)=  \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_{V_2} d^3y G(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \rho(\vec{y})$
For phi(x) in V2 there is no dependence on any function that is inside V1. That implies that the potential, and thus the electric field, is not affected by any charges inside of the hollow conductor.
If instead one analyzes this situation with Gauß' law, observing a big volume outside of the conductor that contains the conductor, you get that changing $\rho$ (in the sense of changing the total charge inside of the hollow conductor) changes the electric flux through the outisde surface, directly implying that the electric field outside is changed as well.
My hypothesis: The idea that you can define the potential on the surface AND the potential at infinity to be zero is non-physical. If you set the zero point of the potential to be a surface, the potential cannot physically be 0 at infinity, that would mean it takes 0-0=0 work to bring a particle from infinity to the surface of the conductor, which is physically not sensible.

The details of the field inside a hollow conductor are invisible from the outside. However, the total charge of the conductor and its contents is visible.

Why are you setting both potentials to zero in the first place?  That's possible, but only in the case where there is zero total charge in the conductor.  Try setting only the potential at infinity to zero, and finding the potential at the surface of the sphere based on that.

I think the problem is that in the first case, you considered the conductor as a boundary, i.e., not a physical object, but a mathematical object imposing a geometric condition, let would say.
To analyse it through Gauss law, however, we need to be more careful. Mathematically, the domain is not simple connected anymore, so Gauss theorem does not apply for a region containing the conductor. Physically, we know by Faraday's cage principle that the field outside should be null, so the field varies discontinuously in the conductor surface. It is caused by conducting surface charges, that flows in a way to cancel the field outside. The conducting charge in the surface should be $-Q$, for a charge $Q$ inside the conductor. If you take it in account in Gauss law, it is possible to apply Gauss law and obtain the correct answer.
Your calculations are correct and basically you demonstrated the Faraday's cage law. What has no physical meaning is to impose null field in the conductors surface without considering it's conducting charges


we know that the surface of a conductor is an equipotential surface, so we can set that potential= 0 because the potential is only determined up to a constant, and we want the potential to be zero at infinity

The surface of a conductor is an equipotential surface, and infinity is also an equipotential surface. Either one may be arbitrarily set to zero, but not both.
What you can do is “ground” or “earth” the conductor. This is basically connecting the conductor to infinity with another conductor. It makes the whole thing one equipotential surface.

I am having trouble understanding why this equation doesn't imply that the E-field outside a conductor isn't affected by what's inside the conductor

Indeed, the field outside is not affected by the field inside the hollow. Remember, charge is conserved. So if you increase the charge in the hollow then the conductor itself will have acquired an opposite charge.
As charge moves around inside the hollow, the interior surface charges will redistribute to cancel the field.

If instead one analyzes this situation with Gauß' law, observing a big volume outside of the conductor that contains the conductor, you get that changing ρ (in the sense of changing the total charge inside of the hollow conductor) changes the electric flux through the outisde surface, directly implying that the electric field outside is changed as well

This (changing $\rho$) is incorrect because it violates the conservation of charge. You cannot change the total charge inside the hollow conductor. If you increase the charge in the hollow then you must decrease the charge on the conductor. The net charge is necessarily unchanged.
The other way to change the charge inside the hollow would be to transport charge from outside. As the charge approaches, that would alter the field. But once the charge is inside the conductor it will no longer alter the field further.
All the above assumes that everything is done slowly enough to remain in the electro quasi static condition
